# DAX to aggregate only for values from Lookup Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

My sample source data is following with two tables

`key`

```
|           key           |
|-------|---------|-------|
| site  | service | month |
|-------|---------|-------|
| site1 | serv1   | 1     |
| site1 | serv1   | 2     |
| site1 | serv1   | 3     |
| site1 | serv1   | 4     |
| site1 | serv1   | 5     |
| site2 | serv1   | 1     |
| site2 | serv1   | 2     |
| site2 | serv1   | 3     |
| site2 | serv1   | 4     |
| site3 | serv1   | 1     |
| site3 | serv1   | 2     |
| site3 | serv1   | 3     |
| site3 | serv1   | 4     |
| site3 | serv1   | 5     |
| site3 | serv1   | 6     |
| site3 | serv1   | 7     |
| site4 | serv1   | 1     |
| site4 | serv1   | 2     |
| site4 | serv1   | 3     |
| site4 | serv1   | 4     |
```

and `lookup`

```
| Lookup |
|--------|
| site   |
|--------|
| site1  |
| site3  |
| site4  |
```

I am building a matrix viz by bringing site,service,month from key tbl and counting how many total months are there by each site-service but I only want to show the  aggregation for sites that only appear in Lookup.

My desired result is following, i.e. `site2` does not appear in `lookup` and I don't want any aggregation to be returned for that.

```
|            Result                |
|--------|---------|-------|-------|
| site   | service | month | Count |
|--------|---------|-------|-------|
| site1  | serv1   | 1     | 5     |
| site1  | serv1   | 2     | 5     |
| site1  | serv1   | 3     | 5     |
| site1  | serv1   | 4     | 5     |
| site1  | serv1   | 5     | 5     |
| site3  | serv1   | 1     | 7     |
| site3  | serv1   | 2     | 7     |
| site3  | serv1   | 3     | 7     |
| site3  | serv1   | 4     | 7     |
| site3  | serv1   | 5     | 7     |
| site3  | serv1   | 6     | 7     |
| site3  | serv1   | 7     | 7     |
| site4  | serv1   | 1     | 4     |
| site4  | serv1   | 2     | 4     |
| site4  | serv1   | 3     | 4     |
| site4  | serv1   | 4     | 4     |
```

I have so far tried with these two measures

```
countSiteService =
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( 'key'[month] ), REMOVEFILTERS ( 'key'[month] ) )

countSiteServiceLookup =
CALCULATE (
    [countSiteService],
    TREATAS ( VALUES ( Lookup[site] ), 'key'[site] )
)
```

But they don't give me what I want

[image: Currrent]

Both the tables are currently **`disconnected`**. But even if I connect them on site, the result does not differ.

How can I achieve the end result with the current model and ***not by putting any hardcoded filters on the filter pane at all***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have gives the total `5 + 7 + 4 = 16` since you're overriding the site filter context.

I suspect you want something more like this:

```
countSiteServiceLookup =
CALCULATE (
    [countSiteService],
    KEEPFILTERS ( 'key'[site] IN VALUES ( Lookup[site] ) )
)
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for this and I tried out. It is good. But how can I also make this measure to return the total count as 16 on the subtotal level, i.e. I want to show 16 as the subtotal count. It currently shows 4.

Comment: It shows 16 when I change the measure as I specified. I've added a screenshot of what I see.